# Extract the property

Tags: json, reactjs, properties, extract

Ok i have this json object. I adding it to localstorage

It's .net and React.

```
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
```

And i need to extract auth_token:

```
"{\n  \"id\": \"24625a45-5079-46be-8241-481661d747e9\",\n  \"auth_token\": \"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ0ZXN0QGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImp0aSI6IjdkMjVlNjRmLTM1YzQtNDMzMi04NWQyLTNhYzlhNTFiZTBiYyIsImlhdCI6MTUzNDAxODUxMSwicm9sIjoiYXBpX2FjY2VzcyIsImlkIjoiMjQ2MjVhNDUtNTA3OS00NmJlLTgyNDEtNDgxNjYxZDc0N2U5IiwibmJmIjoxNTM0MDE4NTEwLCJleHAiOjE1MzQwNDAxMTAsImlzcyI6IndlYkFwaSIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAwMC8ifQ.Gmtft6TGYxFkc9r0GHqr7ed4ntZwa3kVfb2WJ9M8aBI\",\n  \"expires_in\": 21600\n}"
```

How can i extract it?

I using `user.auth_token`. It's don't works.

Refresh, anyone know how solve this type of problem.

---

Here is solution:

```
export function authHeader() {
    // return authorization header with jwt token
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    const userparsed = JSON.parse(user)

        return { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + userparsed.auth_token };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read it back from localStorage you will need to parse the string as JSON like so

```js
const stringFromLocalStorage = "{\n  \"id\": \"24625a45-5079-46be-8241-481661d747e9\",\n  \"auth_token\": \"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ0ZXN0QGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImp0aSI6IjdkMjVlNjRmLTM1YzQtNDMzMi04NWQyLTNhYzlhNTFiZTBiYyIsImlhdCI6MTUzNDAxODUxMSwicm9sIjoiYXBpX2FjY2VzcyIsImlkIjoiMjQ2MjVhNDUtNTA3OS00NmJlLTgyNDEtNDgxNjYxZDc0N2U5IiwibmJmIjoxNTM0MDE4NTEwLCJleHAiOjE1MzQwNDAxMTAsImlzcyI6IndlYkFwaSIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAwMC8ifQ.Gmtft6TGYxFkc9r0GHqr7ed4ntZwa3kVfb2WJ9M8aBI\",\n  \"expires_in\": 21600\n}";


const user = JSON.parse(stringFromLocalStorage);

console.log(user.auth_token);
```

In your case,

```
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
const fetchedUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
console.log('Auth Token', fetchedUser.auth_token);
```

Comment: Hmm stringFromLocalStorage = user ?

if  "{\n id (...)|" is variable?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I have updated my answer to fetch `user` from `localStorage`.

Comment: When i using i get: Auth Token undefined

Comment: Have you ensured that the code I have suggested runs after `localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));` ?

Comment: Yes, first i setItem to localstorage in login function localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));. It's works well it's save json object to localstorage.  Next step is: const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')); And after  this function return undefined on user.auth_token, and return user well